# iOS - GMSMapView display language

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

How to display google maps labels in different language? 
Not in default language,taken from International settings?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the language on GoogleMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38075630/how-to-change-the-language-on-googlemap)

Answer (score 0):

Not currently possible, as of SDK 1.8.

Comment: is it possible now?

Comment: I'm voting to delete this answer ([from review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/20540485)) as it is no longer valid as of August 2018 (see other answer).

Comment: This should be a comment on the original question.