# How to change the language on GoogleMap?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I use **GMSMapView** from Google Maps iOS SDK in my application. 
I can change app language in settings page. 
How to change language on map in runtime?

I can reload or recreate map on this method

```
(void)prepareMap
{
    [self.viewForMap removeAllSubviews];
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longtitude];
    GMSMapView *mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:rect camera:camera];
    [self.viewForMap addSubview:mapView];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered in Using the Google Maps APIs - [How can I get the Google Maps APIs to display in a language other than English?](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq):

> By default the API will attempt to load the most appropriate language based on the users location or browser settings. Some APIs allow you to explicitly set a language when you make a request.

From there, you may add `language` parameter in your HTTPS request in some Google Maps APIs. However, for some APIs that doesn't allow this, you have to first determine the current location with the use of [Core Location Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/) as suggested in this SO post - [iphone default map app open with different language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746298/iphone-default-map-app-open-with-different-language).