# Google Maps iOS in language Change Programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, localization, google-maps-sdk-ios

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/%D8%B9%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%B1/id879992882?mt=8

in this app its clearly visible that Language of Google Maps is in arabic, I have this application installed on my iPhone & language is English, so this means we don't need to change device language to get the Google maps in arabic, like in the app whose link is mentioned.

Any clue or help will be highly appreciable to implement this feature.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the language on GoogleMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38075630/how-to-change-the-language-on-googlemap)

Comment: @PeterTutervai its can be duplicate but the description you can read clearly that the app I mentioned has solution of this requirement, which is not available in the link you have mentioned, I also read it last night after finding nothing I considered to post my question.

Comment: I'm not sure if I see how they have a solution for this. They took a screenshot of Google Maps shown in Arabic, which if you read the question I linked should happen if the device's location or settings indicate that Google Maps should display in Arabic. If you see their map in English on your phone that just proves that they aren't changing the language themselves, but Google picks up a setting on your phone that's different from what they had when taking the screenshot. Or I understood you wrong, but then please explain the issue again ;)

Comment: Actually, I have installed this app in Pakistan, my store ID account is also made for Pakistani Store. But when I have installed this app and watch the maps, it has Arabic labels, not a single english label while my own device language is default (English). I have searched a lot about it. Even the google haven't provided any facility in iOS SDK to change language of labels. 
I have sent them mail to inquire about it. May be they can enlighten me about it. 
But thanks for your concern, if U still think its a duplicate I will delete my question. And we shall discuss it there.

Comment: I have got solution, we need to change the app language to arabic forcefully that will tell the app that device's language is arabic while its not. I can do it now